# How to search string in another string

Tags: java, string

I am trying to create a program which will be able to search a user inputed string for a specific word, and count the number of times that word is repeated.

For example I want the program to function like this:

> Please enter a string of your choice:
>
> kelowna is a nice city, kelowna is my home.
>
> Enter a word for which you would like to search for:
>
> kelowna
>
> The word Kelowna was found 2 times.

How would I go about doing this? My initial approach was to use loops, but that hasn't got me too far.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FinalPracc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("please enter a string of you choice: ");
        String a = s1.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the word you would like to search for: ");
        String b = s1.nextLine();

        int aa = a.length();
        int bb = b.length();

        if (a.contains(b)) {
            System.out.println("word found");
            int c = a.indexOf(b);
            int
            if (
        }
    }
    /* ADD YOUR CODE HERE */
}
```

Comment: What i have soo far will only count if the word is used once, i want the program to count the total number of repitions of the word. Does that make sense? Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Kelowna is overrated.

Comment: Kelowna is the California of Canada! Dont be jealous man ;)

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be that if you find the word, modify the search string to remove everything before and including the word, then search again:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 

    Scanner s1=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("please enter a string of you choice: ");
    String a=s1.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the word you would like to search for: ");
    String b=s1.nextLine();

    int count = 0;
    while(b.contains(a)) {
        count++;
        int pos = b.indexOf(a);
        b = b.substring(pos + a.length());
    }

    if (count > 0){
        System.out.println("word found " + count + " times");
    } else {
        System.out.println("word not found");
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Alternatively, if you don't want to call substring in a loop, you could use the form of indexOf that takes a starting index for the search. In this case, your loop might look like:

```
    int count = 0;
    int searchIndex = 0;
    while((searchIndex = b.indexOf(a, searchIndex)) > -1) {
        count++;
        searchIndex += a.length();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like while(a.contains(b))
and set up a counter by one every time a word is found and cut everything until the last sign of the found word every loop round.

Comment: smart man haha.... i will give that a shot and let you know how it goes. Cant belive i didnt think of that ! Thanks

Comment: No Problem ;-) Sometimes youre stuck in an idea and some quick fresh look could solve it. Thats why we are here! Have fun coding mate!

Comment: while (a.contains(b)){
      count=count+1;
      String x=a.replace(b,"");
    System.out.println(count);
    }

Comment: its putting me into an infinite loop?

Comment: First it should be `b.contains(a)`, then you need `b=b.replace(a, "");`. Even then, I'm not sure it would work as you expect.